# How do I commit my GIT project to SVN?

Tags: git, svn

I have a project that I have been working on locally with Git but my work uses SVN and I want to add it to their SVN server. How would I do that?

I think this is what I want to do but I am not sure...

> git svn init <SVN_PROJECT_URL>

If that is correct, does the URL need to exists before I init?

Comment: Bah, too short.  See my answer instead. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn) will get you what you want.  The linked topic covers a step-by-step instruction on pushing an exisiting GIT repo to SVN.

Hope that helps!